# Drawing without creating a continuous line in Android Studio

Tags: android, api, draw

I made a class which lets me to draw, but it has two problems:
1)It makes a continuous line instead of separated ones. How can I improve it?
2)Is it possible to track the coordinates of the lines made by the user to check, for example, if there are symmetries in the draw?

```
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            canvas.drawBitmap( mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            canvas.drawPath( mPath,  mPaint);
            canvas.drawPath( circlePath,  circlePaint);
        }

        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }

        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;

                circlePath.reset();
                circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
            }
        }

        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            circlePath.reset();
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath,  mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw
            mPath.reset();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touch_start(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touch_up();
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't understand your 2nd question, but for 1st you need to create a new path every time rather than reset the old one

Comment: @bvk256 Sorry, I'm Italian so probably I wrote something wrong. I would like to compare two lines wrote by the user and check if they are symmetric. For example, if the user draw an heptagon (with a continuous line, so it is saved in a singular Path) on the right side of the screen, I would like to check if on the other side there its opposite reflected.